# What visa do I need to apply for going to Russia?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, russia, transit-visas

I am an Indian citizen. My final destination is Venice (Italy) through Moscow (48 hour layover) from the same airport. Travel blogs says that I don't need transit visa if I am not crossing the immigration gate for 24-hours but on above that I need to apply for transit visa. However my travel plans are:

1. India to Moscow (through Aeroflot)
2. Staying in Moscow for 48 hours
3. Moscow to Venice (through Aeroflot and same airport)

I need to apply transit visa for sure but can I apply at the Russian Airport transit zone?

Comment: As a rule, Russian visas must be obtained beforehand.

Answer (score 6):

If you must leave the airport for a layover you will need to get a transit visa in advance. There is no visa on arrival. You can [fill out the application online](https://visa.kdmid.ru/), then print it out and submit it.

For a transit visa you will need to submit:

- Your passport, which must already contain your visa for your destination. (In your case, this is your Schengen visa.)
- Proof of your paid flight tickets.
- One standard passport type photo.
- Visa fees.

After you have filed the online application, you will [submit the application and your documents to VFS Global](https://www.vfsglobal.com/Russia/India/), which now handles visa processing for Russia in India.

Comment: @Michale I am also facing very similar problem. It means that after submitting the application I need to submit all the docs to Embassy / Consulate to get my transit visa?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of relying on travel blogs, I suggest you check the database that airline companies use. For example, [the website of KLM Royal Dutch Airlines](https://www.klm.com/travel/ch_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm). After you identified what kind of visa you need (if any), you should check the embassy's website or call them (you might get trouble getting through, but once you did, they will help you). As far as I know, all types of Russian visitors visas are issued either by embassy's visa center directly or by travel agencies **outside of Russia**.